# Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

Tags: javascript

I am getting error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement

on `break;`, i am want to stop `for` loop if server return 5. I am using below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getrblstatus(rbl, hash) {
        var rblhosts = [<?php echo $rblhosts ?>];
        var ActiveRbls = rblhosts.length;
        var progress = '1';
        for (i = 0; i < ActiveRbls; i++) {
            ///// Post data to server /////
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $site_url?>/includes/lib/ajax.php',
                data: {
                    action: 'getrblstatus',
                    for: rbl,
                    hash: hash,
                    rbl_host: rblhosts[i]
                },
                type: 'post',
                success: function (data) {
                    var percent = (progress/ActiveRbls)*100;
                    percent = percent.toFixed(2);
                    if(data == 5) {
                        console.log('Hash not correct');
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#rbl_table > tbody').append(data);
                        $('#progressbar').width(percent+'%');
                        $("#progressbar").html(percent+"% Completed");
                        progress ++;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No you cannot use break inside a function . Move the code to some function and use return statement instead of break

Comment: Yes, i am using this code inside function whenever it showing error

Comment: Correct indentation and formatting usually assists in finding syntax errors since the problem usually sticks out (in both meanings of the word). Please take some time on your next post to correctly format your code - you might even find the error in the process.

Comment: use return statement instead of break

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You can't use `break` or `continue` in callback functions, because the loop will already be done before the callbacks are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant mix asynchronous code (the AJAX call) with synchronous code (for/break/continue). So you may `await` the AJAX request:

```
async function getrblstatus(rbl, hash) {
    var hosts = [<?php echo $rblhosts ?>], progress = 1;
    for (const rbl_host of hosts) {
        const data = await new Promise((success, error) => $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $site_url?>/includes/lib/ajax.php',
            data: {
                action: 'getrblstatus',
                for: rbl,
                hash: hash,
                rbl_host
            },
            type: 'post', success

        }));
        var percent = (progress++ / hosts.length) * 100;

        if(data == 5) {
            console.log('Hash not correct');
            break;
        }
        else {
            $('#rbl_table > tbody').append(data);
            $('#progressbar').width(percent+'%');
            $("#progressbar").html(percent+"% Completed");
        }
    }
}
```

Due to `await`, the `break;` is on the `for` loop level.